# Eclipse CDT not working with OpenCV 2.0 integrated with Cygwin compiler

Tags: c++, c, opencv, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I have done all the necessary job like adding "c:/cygwin/bin" to system path, I have also set the **include** path under project->properties->c/c++ build->setting and also set the linker library search path.
Now when I include file like #include"cv.h", it gives no error, but when I run the program error comes like
`undefined reference to '_cvGetSize'`
I have included the necessary files, and read lots of tutorials that are available but still I couldn't able to run my code, please help me

Comment: Apparently you didn't linked your project with the OpenCV libraries. Just pointing the path of the libraries won't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always recommend that before jumping to an IDE you make sure your system is installed and configured correctly by attempting to compile an application on the cmd-line:

```
g++ flann.cpp -o flann `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

or:

```
g++ flann.cpp -o flann -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

Apparently you didn't link your project with the opencv libraries, which is being achieved in the cmd above with: `-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann`.

That missing symbol is defined in one of these libraries.

Comment: i am using window 7, and when i add these to libraries(-l), then it gives one more error like `cannot find -lopencv_core`.<br>i have spent 2 days on this but still i couldn't able to run my project :(

Comment: Open the directory of where the libraries are, and paste their names here. Most probably OpenCV 2.0 has a slight variation in the names of the files. Also, can't you use Visual Studio Express (which is free)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually i was adding the full name like filename.dll.a, but only filename was required